# Reactjs Select v2 - How to handle Ajax Typing?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-select

I am using [reactjs select 2](https://deploy-preview-2289--react-select.netlify.com/home)  but I don't know how to make it work so that when a user types something in a ajax request is made and the results are sent back.

I see it has some async options but I don't get how it works and how I would get it to work with axios.

I come up with this but it is kinda laggy when a user types(probably because it is re-rendering it after each type) and when the user selects a choice the value disappears.

```js
export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ""};
  }

  onInputChange(option) {
    this.getOptionsAsync(option)

}
getOptionsAsync(newInput) {
  var that = this;
  console.log("ffd", newInput)
  axios.get(`https://localhost:44343/api/States/GetStatesByText?text=${newInput}`)
    .then(function (response) {    
      var formatedResults = response.data.map((x)=> {
        return {value: x.id, label: x.name}
      })
      that.setState({
          options: formatedResults,
          value: newInput
      })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

    });   
}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.value, "value")
    return (
      <div className="test">
      <Select
        onInputChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.state.value}
        options={this.state.options }
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey chobo, I later needed to do something with react-select again and I found that react-virtualized-select provided a huge speed improvement. Hope that you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to be doing an api call every single time that you type a letter with the current way you're doing things. I would recommend just loading the states once at the beginning, perhaps in your ComponentDidMount() method.

If you pass the `isSearchable` prop to React-Select it will automatically work as a filter anyways.

Another thing I've had to do in this case which I believe will fix your change problem is to make sure it calls the handler on change not just on input change.

Pass this prop:

```js
<Select
    value={this.state.value}
    options={this.state.options }
    onChange={value => {
        if (value) this.onInputChange(value)
        else this.onInputChange('')
      }
  />
```

Due to the way `this` is automatically bound to arrow functions, you won't have to bind to `thi`s if you change your `onInputChange` to the following:

```js
  onInputChange = (value) => {
    this.getOptionsAsync(value)
}
```

Finally, you should be setting the state in the above function so the value is stored.

```js
  onInputChange = (value) => {
    this.getOptionsAsync(value)
    this.setState({value})
}
```

Comment: hmm, I don't want to load the data all on load because I think there is like 4000 records in the database as it's look at all states/provinces in the entire world. I could do first a box with country then filter down and only show states/provinces of that country but in this area of the page that is not what I am going for.

Comment: Yes that didn't make sense at all. It's probably much better caching these values at the server.